# Phase locked loop for Grid synchronization

Tags: analog, integrated-circuit, pll, single-phase

Is there any IC available to implement PLL for the single-phase grid-connected inverter?

one solution that I came across is using Texas instruments C2000 series microcontrollers and I also searched PLL ICs but I found digital PLLs but is there any IC specifically to implement analog PLL that generates sin wave for the grid synchronization?

Comment: 60 Hz is slow enough that a general purpose microcontroller is likely to be able to perform this function, giving you maximum flexibility to implement the PLL however you like.

Comment: More than control that you could implement using a microcontroller coupled with fast Hall effect current and voltage sensing IC, the actual converter design is going to be much more complex to ensure a steady flow of power post synchronization with an infinite source.

Comment: If all you want to do is to generate a sine wave that's phase-locked to the incoming electrical power, you can do this with a processor in an SO-8 package and maybe a couple of scaling resistors.  That's smaller than each of the two or three or four capacitors that you'd need to implement your 60Hz oscillator and sub-6Hz loop filter in an all-analog solution.  Far less expensive, too.

Comment: The reason you find the PLL implemented in a DSP is because, usually, you'd not be using that DSP to do only the PLL, but additional things, like PQ/DQ transform, calculation of powers, SPWM/SVPWM/whateverPWM, protections, etc. So it wouldn't be very profitable to make a dedicated IC when that IC would need other dedicated ICs, as well. A DSP is much cheaper, and the software is up to the user.

Comment: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4046b.pdf?ts=1606641457490&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F